# Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable?

Tags: python, django, environment-variables, virtual, pythonpath

I am using ubuntu 16.04. Now I am starting my first Django project. Please check this error:

```
(unix-9PXH2taC) unix@unix:~/Desktop/django/test_project$** python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

How did you install it ?

For pip and conda, check if you are in correct environment.

If you did an apt install (or apt-get install), the PYTHONPATH is not reflected until you source .bashrc in your home directory. Log-out and log-in (or type source ~/.bashrc in your terminal).